# Format httpclient response for *ngFor?

Tags: javascript, angular

Hi I was wondering if anyone could help me solve a small problem. 
I am received data from my rest api which is returned as an array with objects inside. 
Once I get it to my service I try to transform the data and push it to a subject so that it can inform my component that the data is here or updated. 
When i console.log the data I get

```
0:{code: "AUH", name: "Abu Dhabi"}
1:{code: "ALY", name: "Alexandria"}
2:{code: "LTS", name: "Altus"}
3:{code: "ANK", name: "Ankara"}
4:{code: "AIY", name: "Atlantic City"}
5:{code: "BAK", name: "Baku"}
6:{code: "BKK", name: "Bangkok"}
7:{code: "EAP", name: "Basel"}
8:{code: "BJS", name: "Beijing"}
```

So when I try and use my *ngFor I get [object]p[Object]
How can I format this to work with *ngFor?

city-list.component.html

```js
import { CityService } from "./services/city-list.service";
import { Component, OnInit, OnDestroy } from "@angular/core";
import { City } from "../cities/models/city";
import { Subscription } from "rxjs";

@Component({
  selector: "<app-cities></app-cities>",
  templateUrl: "./city-list.component.html"
})
export class CityListComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  cities: City[];
  private citiesSub: Subscription; // so as to unsubscribe if page changes/ memory leak

  constructor(public cityService: CityService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.cityService.getCities();
    this.citiesSub = this.cityService
      .getCityUpdateListener()
      .subscribe((cities) => {
       this.cities = cities;
      });



    // 1st value: when data emit 2nd value: error emit, 3rd value function for when no more data is available
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.citiesSub.unsubscribe();
  }
}
// subject is an observable but you can call next on them to emit a change when you want
```

"service"

```
import { Subject } from 'rxjs';
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {HttpClient} from '@angular/common/http';

import { map } from "rxjs/operators";

import {City} from '../models/city';

@Injectable()
export class CityService {
  cities: City[] = [];
  private updatedCities = new Subject<City[]>();


  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

 getCities() {
  this.http.get<{message: string; cities: City[]}>('http://localhost:3000/cities')
  .pipe(
    map((cityData)=>{

      return cityData.cities.map(city=>{
        return{
          code: city.code,
          name: city.name
        };
      });
    })
)
  .subscribe((transCity) => {
    this.cities = transCity;
    console.log(this.cities);
    this.updatedCities.next([...this.cities]);
  });
  }

  getCityUpdateListener() {
    return this.updatedCities.asObservable();
  }

}
```

Comment: That’s the code?

Comment: Can you provide at stackbiz , is it possible , how ever i answered might work for you try it out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use the `json` pipe:

```
<div *ngFor="let item of response">{{ item | json }}</div>
```

If you want to display it in "pretty" instead of as json, you need to access the individual fields of the item and format it in the desired way.

Answer (score 1):

try as below , first get keys form reponse object you are receiving from http call and then go through each key in html , might resole your issue

in ts file

```
//response is data you received after making http call, list of cities in your case 
keys = Object.keys(response);
```

in html file

```
<div *ngFor="let key of keys">
  {{response[key].code }}  {{response[key].name }}
</div>
```

this should work based on response you are getting from server

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the issue here is that you're not actually returning an array of `City`, instead you're returning a dictionary or `Map<City>`. You'll probably want to iterate over your response and map it to the correct type.

```
this.citiesSub = this.cityService
      .getCityUpdateListener()
      .subscribe((cityMap) => {
        this.cities = [ ...cityMap.values() ]
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Asuming you are using httpClient(new released in angular5) then there is no need of the map() and pipe() functions, results are mapped to json by default you just have to subscribe to the service
this is how it would look your new service class

```
import { Subject } from 'rxjs';
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {HttpClient} from '@angular/common/http';

import { map } from "rxjs/operators";

import {City} from '../models/city';

@Injectable()
export class CityService {
  cities: City[] = [];
  private updatedCities = new Subject<City[]>();


  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  getCities() {
    return this.http.get<City[]>('http://localhost:3000/cities')//http.get<any> also work but for type safety i am asuming City[] array have the same structure.      
  }

  getCityUpdateListener() {
    return this.updatedCities.asObservable();
  }

}
```

Then in your component you would have to subscrive to that service and use it

```
    constructor(public cityService: CityService) {
       this.cityService.getCities().subscribe(cities => {
           this.cities = cities;
           console.log(cities);

       }, error=> {console.log(error)});//handling errors
     }

  ngOnInit() {  }  // just moved the service call to the constructor of the component
```

I hope this solve your problem,
Thanks